# How get language_code in the response using 'Fulfillment URL' in Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am using 'Fulfillment URL' in the section 'Actions' in console.actions.google
I put an URL and I have a lambda to do treatments but I don't see a property 'language_code' and I would like to use it.

Any idea if I have to active an option or something to get this information ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dialogflow and the Node.js library, you can use [`conv.user.locale`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_actionssdk_conversation_user_.user.html#locale).

In plain JSON it would be [`originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.locale`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json).